# Bottom border override normal on hover

Tags: css

Hey I can't understand if there is any easy way to solve this: 
I want the black border to be on top of the blue border not extend the height of the navigation.

I've looked at inset and adding bottom in the a but I want to override the one from .navigationbar

HTML

```
<nav class="navigationbar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="index.html">One</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="two.html">Two</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="three.html">Three</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.navigationbar {
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: .1em solid #0000FF;
}

.navigationbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navigationbar ul li {
  float: left;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navigationbar ul li a {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.navigationbar ul li a:hover {
  background: #0000FF;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: .1em solid #000000;
}

.navigationbar img {
  float: left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/55r2e9bq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just set the border and change its color later?

```
.navigationbar ul li a 
{
    border-bottom: .1em solid transparent;
}

.navigationbar ul li a:hover
{
    border-bottom-color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The border you are seeing comes from the rule `.navigationbar ul li a:hover{...}` where you have `border-bottom: .1em solid #000000;`. It is not extending to 100% of width of the navigation bar, but is causing it becomes higher. 
If you want the `navigationbar`stays of the same height you should assign the border also to the normal state of the `a` element then you can change its color to whatever you want.

This way:

```
.navigationbar ul li a {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;

  border-bottom: .1em solid #ffcc00; /* add this property with the same value of the `:hover` state */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `border-bottom: 0.1em solid #000000;` to `.navigationbar ul li a` to avoid that movement/height increase:

https://jsfiddle.net/p7L7adhe/1/